Add native files from NuGet package to .NET application output directory
I am trying to get native files installed alongside a .NET 8.0 C# assembly from a NuGet package.  The goal is to use P/Invoke to call APIs in a native DLL, so I have to know where that DLL is located relative to the C# application using the package, and the DLL's dependencies must be found.
I tried the runtimes hierarchy mentioned here, but that didn't work.  I put the native files in the runtimes\net8.0\native directory in the package, and I see them listed in obj\project.assets.json in "runtimeTargets", but when I build the solution, they are not copied to the output directory, so I can't find the API DLL and it wouldn't find its dependencies.
Following the advice in this answer, I tried to arrange for the native files to be installed in the output directory for a C# Console Application, but the copy step doesn't run.
In that case, my NuGet package contained the native files in the build directory along with the following Project.targets file:
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeDependencies
      Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*.*"
      Exclude="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)*.targets"
    />
    <None Include="@(NativeDependencies)">
      <Link>%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I installed my NuGet package in the console application; there were no errors.  I built the solution, but the native files were not copied/linked.
I see the Project.targets file referenced in obj/Project.csproj.nuget.g.targets, so seemingly there's an appropriate reference to Project.targets, but it never runs:
    <Import Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)...\build\Project.targets" Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)...\build\Project.targets')" />


I set Visual Studio to run MSBuild with diagnostic level output, but see no mention of "Project.targets" or "NativeDependencies".
What have I missed?

If you only need to support projects that reference your package with .NET 6+, then you don't need your own props/targets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-files-in-net-packages#example-1   Otherwise, build your test project with the -bl argument, which creates a file msbuild.binlog, then open it with https://msbuildlog.com and do lots of searching and learning to figure out why it doesn't work.

@zivkan, I'll update my question as I forgot to mention that the C# assembly targets .NET 8, but I fail to understand how that addresses the issue. I need to deliver native DLLs along with the .NET assembly. The first link you mentioned is one I examined previously. I forgot that I also tried putting the native DLLs in the runtimes directory in the package, but they weren't installed then, either; I'll include that in the question, too.

It seems you constructed the runtime directory incorrectly - can you try with  e.g. runtimes/win-x64/native? this should copy it correclty automatically and you can add alternatives into different RIDs (linux-x64, win-arm64 etc)

@MartinUllrich, using runtimes/win-x64/native does work without requiring the relative pathname in the source. I had read {rid} in all sections of this page as being the same. It seems the set of RIDs for managed resources, for which I got net8.0, is different than the set for native resources, for which you suggested win-x64.

As described here, and clarified by @Martin Ullrich, it was enough to put the native files in runtimes\win-x64\native for my case†.  I then only needed to reference the DLL via [DllImport("name")].  (I had tried that before and couldn't seem to get it to work, hence the posted question, but there were other issues that I missed then.)
My Project.nuspec contains the following:
  <files>
    ...
    <file src="path\*.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native"/>
  </files>

After installing the package and building the C# console application, the native DLLs are copied to, for example, ...\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0\runtimes\win-x64\native.  The DllImport shown above, in the .cs file using P/Invoke, then finds the native DLL with the required APIs without needing any path information.
† I previously misapprehended net8.0 as the RID to use, but there are different RIDs for native versus managed runtimes.  When I used net8.0 rather than win-x64, I needed the native runtimes' relative pathname in my source: [DllImport("runtimes\\net8.0\\native\\name")].

You shouldn't need to provide a path in DllImport, just the name. The .NET SDK and runtime (via the deps.json file) handle the rest.

Also, you can avoid the downside by packing the project file (csproj?) via dotnet pack, rand stop using a custom nuspec file.  This way you can use $(TargetFramework) in your PackagePath metadata, and it'll automatically update when the project property does.

@zivkan, using just the native DLL filename, without the relative path, does not work.

@zivkan, thanks for the dotnet pack suggestion. Unfortunately, this packaging work is part of a CMake project that includes generating two of the .cs files compiled in the project, and inserts content into the .nuspec, including version information, so I don't think it's possible to manage everything from Visual Studio and, hence, use dotnet pack. I could be wrong, however.

@zivkan, as you can see, @MartinUllrich helped me understand my RID mistake for the native files so I was able to eliminate the path in the DllImport.
